# Classifying space of bundles over bundles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

Consider a sufficiently nice topological space $X$ as well as topological groups $G$ and $H$. Consider the functor $F$ that associates to $X$ the set of all isomorphism classes of all principal $H$-bundles $\pi_H\colon P_H\twoheadrightarrow P_G$ on all principal $G$-bundles $\pi_G\colon P_G\twoheadrightarrow X$ on $X$. I think that this would be representable by the [Brown representability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%27s_representability_theorem), i.e. there is a topological space $C_{G,H}$ such that $[X,C_{G,H}]$ is in bijection with the isomorphism classes of such bundles-over-bundles ([modulo pointed-vs-unpointed spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285533/classifying-spaces-and-browns-representability-theorem)). But is there an explicit description/characterisation of it?

I am specifically interested in the case where $G=\operatorname U(1)^n$ is a torus (and $H$ is compact Lie); the motivation is that this would describe the so-called [Kaluza–Klein reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory) of gauge fields on nontrivially fibred torus compactifications.

As a special case, the subset of $F(X)$ that corresponds to $H$-bundles on the trivial $n$-torus bundle $\operatorname U(1)^n\times X$ is classified by the $n$-fold iterated free loop space $\mathcal L^n\mathrm BG$; and in the case $n=1$ this object is [well studied](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+loop+space+of+classifying+space). But I don't know how to generalise to arbitary principal torus bundles.

Comment: Your notion of "isomorphism classes" is what one would guess?

Comment: @KonradWaldorf: yes, the obvious notion (in the unpointed case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question right, I think the classifying space can be described like this. Let $Map(G,BH)$ be the space of all continuous maps from $G$ to $BH$. Make the group $G$ act continuously on that function space (using the usual free transitive action of $G$ on the space $G$), and form the associated bundle over $BG$:
$$
EG\times_G Map(G,BH).
$$

Comment: This looks good, I was just about to write this.

Comment: I might be worthwhile to point out that when G is finite, then this is a wreath-product construction: the above is the classifying space a wreath product with normal subgroup $H^{|G|}$, where $G$ permutes  the factors according to left multiplication on itself.

Comment: There's a variant $B(H\wr \Sigma_n)=E\Sigma_n \times_{\Sigma_n} Map(n, BH)$, where n is the finite set, which classifies $P\to Y\to X$ where $Y\to X$ is an n-fold cover and $P\to Y$ a principal H-bundle.